# android: possible to select target sdk **when creating new project**?

Tags: java, android

When creating new project you get "select project template" and then "configure your project" windows. On the second window, there's an option to set *minimum SDK*, but no target SDK for compilation, which is automatically set to a higher version. I can change it later, but this creates various problems (initial activity has features that rely on later versions, etc). Is there any way to set the target SDK **during project creation**??

Answer (score 0):

The answer is **No**. You just can't. And change it inside the gradle config is the only way. Maybe there is reason for Android to configure default target version.